# C# WPF Databinding DataGrid Slow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i've performance issues with my code below. I'm trying to bind two lists with two DataGrids. A DataGrid for each List. I need a two way Binding. Does anyone knows why? Or has sb an advices?

These are my classes

```
    public class Vertices
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double PositionX { get; set; }
    public double PositionY { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsMap { get; set; }
    public bool IsStartEndPoint { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisplay { get; set; }
    public bool IsExit { get; set; }
    public string TextToSpeech { get; set; }

}

public class Edges
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SourceVertex { get; set; }
    public int TargetVertex { get; set; }
    public bool IsNormal { get; set; }
    public bool IsElevatorUp { get; set; }
    public bool IsElevatorDown { get; set; }
    public bool IsStairUp { get; set; }
    public bool IsStairDown { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Code in XAML

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridVertices" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AllVerticesList}"  />
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridEdges" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AllEdgesList}"  />
```

This is my Codebehind

```
            this.DataGridVertices.ItemsSource = AllVerticesList;
        this.DataGridEdges.ItemsSource = AllEdgesList;
```

I'am updating the DataGrid with DataGrid.Items.Refresh();

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding the datagrids with lists, bind them with ObservableCollection.
And set the binding Mode to **TwoWay** and UpdateSourceTrigger to **PropertyChanged** . Now, you don't need to Refresh Datagrid and no need to set the itemsource in the code behind. Simply add, remove update the collection. It will improve the performance.

If you are using binding, don't use codebehind. Or manage everything via codebehind, don't use binding. Using both, can impact the performance. Hope this helps.

Comment: and make sure you are virtualizing the items properly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and make sure you have implemented a custom ObservableCollection with a perfect add range to fire only one event instead of one event by each new element.